# Is there a convenient way to configure noCache and excludeNullProperties parameters for json result in struts2?

Tags: json, struts2

I am using struts-json-plugin.2.2.3 for Actions whose result type is json, here is an demo configuration:

```
<action name="dept_*" class="com.XXX.action.DepartmentAction" method="{1}">
        <result name="search">dept_search.jsp</result>
        <result name="search_ajax" type="json"><param name="root">deptList</param><param name="excludeNullProperties">true</param><param name="noCache">true</param></result>
        <result name="save" type="json"><param name="root">jsonResult</param><param name="excludeNullProperties">true</param><param name="noCache">true</param></result>
        <result name="count" type="json"><param name="root">pageCount</param><param name="excludeNullProperties">true</param><param name="noCache">true</param></result>
    </action>
```

This configuration works fine. But for all Actions in my project, `noCache` and `excludeNullProperties` have same configuration value just like code above, so I am searching a way to configure them in one place and used for all. I find in `JSONInterceptor` class, there are same name properties, so I configured like this:

```
  <interceptors>
        <interceptor-stack name="ecsStack">
            <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack"></interceptor-ref>
            <interceptor-ref name="json"><param name="noCache">true</param><param name="excludeNullProperties">true</param><param name="contentType">application/json;charset=utf-8</param></interceptor-ref>
        </interceptor-stack>
    </interceptors>

    <default-interceptor-ref name="ecsStack"></default-interceptor-ref>
```

And remove same configurations in `Action result`, but it does not work as expected, there is no `cache-control`, `expires` and `pragma` information in response headers, and null properties are sent to browser.
So why it does not work?
If there is a convenient way to configure these two parameters?

Comment: The `"json"` interceptor's configuration won't affect a `"json"` result's configuration. I don't *think* there's a way to set result parameters globally, although I could be mistaken. The most convenient might be to just take the existing json result, extend it, and define your own result type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this `result-type` configuration in `struts.xml` file:

```
<result-type name="json" class="org.apache.struts2.json.JSONResult">
  <param name="noCache">true</param>
  <param name="excludeNullProperties">true</param>
</result-type>
```