# In Struts, Is it possible to add a global 'json' result for a package?

Tags: java, json, struts2, struts2-json-plugin

It seems that in order to define a json result for a struts 2 action, you have to define it seperately for each action, in the following way:

```
<action name="someJsonAction" class="com.something.Struts2Action">
    <result type="json">
        <param name="noCache">true</param>
        <param name="excludeNullProperties">true</param>
        <param name="root">jsonString</param>
    </result>
</action>
```

Is it possible to add this as a global result to a package, so that I won't have to include the 3 parameters (noCache, excludeNullProperties, and root) with each action, and instead I can just define a result named 'json' and it would know to inherit those 3 parameters which I described?

Thanks.

Comment: You should check the package if it supports a global result.

Comment: @nikpon Which package?

Comment: Any package, but it should be outpost to the default package.

Comment: @nikpon Well, in my package, I'm able to define global results, however they only seem to work if I don't add a `result type`, e.g `<result name="foo">/foo.jsp</result>` works, but `<result type="json" name="foo>` doesn't.

Comment: Sometimes it works, sometimes is not working, are you sure it works if you place it to the action?

Comment: @nikpon Are you able to help with this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19755939/struts-2-resetting-action-instance-while-its-still-in-interceptor It might be why it sometimes works and other times, doesn't

Comment: You didn't answer my question. That link is a different question. Both answers are correct. What kind of help do you need?

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/15521241/1700321.

Answer (score 0):

Yes of course, there's a way :

See the global results section in the [Documentation](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/result-configuration.html)

```
<global-results>
    <result name="success" type="json">
       <param name="noCache">true</param>
        <param name="excludeNullProperties">true</param>
        <param name="root">jsonString</param>
    </result>
</global-results>
```