# Struts 2 resetting action instance while its still in interceptor

Tags: java, struts2

It seems that if I have two concurrent requests being made to the same action, e.g mysite.com/fooAction, then struts resets the first action's instance while that instance may still be in the interceptor.

E.g, if I have the following code in my interceptor:

```
action =  ai.getAction();
String result = ai.invoke();
logger.debug("Orig action : " + action.toString()  +" , now : " + ai.getAction().toString() );
```

And if I make two concurrent requests to the same action (e.g using javascript), then the line:

```
logger.debug("Orig action : " + action.toString()  +" , now : " + ai.getAction().toString() );
```

produces two different `toString()` codes, showing that the original action was in a different instance than the last action.

This is a big problem, because now, if I had any code in the interceptor, which was setting certain things on my action, e.g doing the following:

```
MyAction action =  (MyAction) ai.getAction();
Auth auth = new Auth ( action.getSession() );
action.setAuth(auth);
action.setCookiesMap( Util.getAllCookies() );
String result = ai.invoke();
```

then there is no guarantee that all those things which I've set on my action are in fact going to be passed to the correct instance. I.e, when `ai.invoke()` is called, it may in fact call a completely different instance of the action, which has different cookies or other data set on it. This could result in different users being given access to each other's data.

Am I correct in all of this? If so, is there a solution to this problem? Because this seems to completely defeat the purpose of interceptors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly - If a single request is made, then the result of printing the action references indicate that they are same.

However if concurrent requests are made, then the action references differ.

If this is indeed so, then its likely due to customizations.

By default, the only place where the 'action' reference is initialized in case of [DefaultActionInvocation is in createAction](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.struts.xwork/xwork-core/2.3.15/com/opensymphony/xwork2/DefaultActionInvocation.java#DefaultActionInvocation.createAction%28java.util.Map%29) which in turn is invoked only in init(ActionProxy) in the same class and which in turn is supposed to be invoked only once and is done from  [prepare() of DefaultActionProxy](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.struts.xwork/xwork-core/2.3.15/com/opensymphony/xwork2/DefaultActionProxy.java#DefaultActionProxy.prepare%28%29) which in turn is only invoked from [createActionProxy() of DefaultActionProxyFactory](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.struts.xwork/xwork-core/2.3.15/com/opensymphony/xwork2/DefaultActionProxyFactory.java#DefaultActionProxyFactory.createActionProxy%28java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.util.Map,boolean,boolean%29).

As such for a given instance of ActionInvocation the action would (should) always be the same.

**Update 2** ([Regarding the example s2 project](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B5dyax9zpxrQQVU5RjlKYTlZcUk/edit?usp=sharing&pli=1)) :

While I did not actually run the code, I did go through it.

The Json interceptor is stateful. However it is required to be stateless. This explains why concurrent requests result in the action instances being different.

As per the interceptor doc [here](http://struts.apache.org/development/2.x/xwork-core/apidocs/com/opensymphony/xwork2/interceptor/Interceptor.html#intercept%28com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionInvocation%29) :

> An interceptor is a stateless class that follows the interceptor
>   pattern, as found in javax.servlet.Filter and in AOP languages.
>   ...
>
> Interceptors must be stateless and not assume that a new instance will
>   be created for each request or Action.

As I understand it :

The first request assigns the local Action instance in the interceptor and goes to sleep.

The second request re-assigns the Action instance (interceptor being singleton) and also goes to sleep.

The first request wakes up and continues with the execution. Upon returning and comparing the action instances again, sees the Action instance in the interceptor from the second request and fetches the action instance for the current request from the ActionInvocation again. They will indeed be different. This explains the observed behaviour. Also, it should be visible even if ai.invoke() or ai.invokeActionOnly() is not called.

Also the 'servletConfig' interceptor is already included in the 'defaultStack' along with a bunch of others. You can find the details [here](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/interceptors.html#Interceptors-TheDefaultConfiguration)

Comment: Please see my edit where I've provided a sample project to test this behavior, its showing that the action reference obtained via `ai.getAction()` is not the same as the reference obtained after `ai.invokeActionOnly()` if the same action class is requested multiple times concurrently.

Comment: @ClickUpvote I have updated the answer. In simple terms, the interceptor should be stateless.

Comment: You're correct. To be clear, I was storing the first `action` as a class field rather than a local variable to the `intercept()` method. So, it was being reset each time the `intercept()` method was called during concurrent requests. Making action a local variable solved the problem. And anyone writing an interceptor in future should remember that interceptors are meant to be singletons.. so they can avoid the same mistake I made.

Comment: @ClickUpvote That's highlighted in the docs in the big red warning box. Also, when asking a question like this, the context of the code matters a *lot*--there's no way to tell from the question that the interceptor is stateful.

Comment: @ClickUpvote Consider looking at a more recent version of the docs; the note about thread safety in the big red box was added in 2007.